# Locuzioni per un rimando ad un'immagine all'interno dell'opera?

Tags: word-usage

Quali sono le locuzioni che posso utilizzare per fare un rimando ad un'immagine presente nel testo che sto scrivendo? In particolare mi chiedevo se fosse accettata la locuzione cfr. per un rimando alle figure.
Quali alternative alla seguente frase:

> Nella parte destra dell'arto (vedi figura 5.1) si possono notare delle ustioni.

Sono comunemente accettate? Per esempio:

> Nella parte destra dell'arto (viz. figura 5.1) si possono notare delle ustioni.

Oppure:

> Nella parte destra dell'arto (cfr. figura 5.1) si possono notare delle ustioni.

Comment: *cfr.* è abbreviazione di *confer*, una delle *latinitates* tanto amate da umanisti e giurisperiti.

Comment: Io di solito uso semplicemente (Figura 5.1) senza nessuna locuzione... Almeno nella letteratura biologica è ciò che viene utilizzato più comunemente.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'abbreviazione *cfr.* è una

> Abbreviazione moderna del lat. *confer* «confronta», usata spec. in testi di studio o di consultazione davanti a citazioni o elementi lessicali su cui si richiama l’attenzione del lettore. Si legge comunemente confronta (come se fosse abbreviazione del verbo italiano).

—http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/cfr/

Quindi va forse vista come un "per saperne di più vedi anche…" piuttosto che un'indicatione specifica. Non credo possa essere usata in generale per una figura, ma ovviamente in certi casi potrebbe avere senso: "la città di Milano sembra immensa, ma in confronto ad altre città (*cfr.* Fig. 1) è piuttosto piccola" dove "fig. 1" può essere una serie di foto aeree di città fra cui Milano ed altre.

*Viz.* invece è una

> Abbreviazione del lat. *videlicet* (v.), usata, con il sign. di «cioè, cioè a dire, ossia», in opere di studio scritte in latino e anche, talvolta, in altra lingua; è un adattamento grafico della scrittura medievale, dove il segno indicava abbreviazione di *-et* (ma anche di altri gruppi di lettere finali).

—http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/viz/

Quindi non è adatta a inirizzare ad una foto o figura.

*Vedi* va ovviamente bene.

In conclusione, hai provato ad *omettere tutto*?

Invece di dire

> Nel Rapporto 2012 in testa alla classifica, con 872 punti, c’è l’Olanda, mentre l’Italia, con 623 punti, si trova al 21° posto (*vedi Figura 1*).

potresti anche dire

> Nel Rapporto 2012 in testa alla classifica, con 872 punti, c’è l’Olanda, mentre l’Italia, con 623 punti, si trova al 21° posto (*Figura 1*).

<sup>Esempio rubato da [qui](http://salutepertutti.comunita.unita.it/2012/07/15/la-classifica-dei-sistemi-sanitari/)</sup>

Comment: Si forse è la cosa migliore!

Answer (score 3):

Non credo proprio che *cfr.* sia accettata qui. Questa abbreviazione significa "confrontare, vedere anche" e si usa genericamente con riferimento a un altro testo, senza indicare un punto preciso. Può indicare ulteriore materiali o argomenti differenti. Se vuole rimandare alla figura **e** confrontarla con un altra figura o con un altro testo, forse, si scrive:

> Nella parte destra dell'arto (vedi figura 5.1) si possono notare delle ustioni (cfr. figura 1.3).

oppure

> Nella parte destra dell'arto si possono notare delle ustioni (cfr. *Autore Grande. Un bel libro. Milano, 2013, capitolo 6*).

Comment: Adesso ho provato con Nngram ed effettivamente non si trovano riferimenti a "cfr. figura 1" allora l'unico è utilizzare "vedi"?

Comment: @GM Sì, per un rimando alla figura si usa "vedi". Un rimando con _cfr. figura_ significherebbe che quella figura dimostra qualcosa diverso da quello che stai dicendo (per esempio, confronta argomenti simili o completamente in opposizione).